# How to allow passing objects to one another that allows

Tags: c++, logging, traits

I am trying to create a logger system that can report logs using the stream operator:

```cpp
// There can be only one transport per logger at the moment
// If there is a need for multiple transport, I want to provide
// a CompositeTransport that combines these transports
logger.setTransport(ConsoleTransport);

logger.log(Severity::Warning) << "This is a warning";
```

I have created the following interface for it:

```cpp
using LogTimestamp = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock>;
using LogTransport = std::function<std::ostream (Severity, LogTimestamp)>;

void Logger::addTransport(LogTransport transport) {
  mTransport = transport;
}

std::ostream Logger::log(Severity severity) {
  auto timestamp = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

  return mTransport(severity, timestamp);
}

std::ostream ConsoleTransport(LogSeverity severity, LogTimestamp timestamp) {
  // This is my custom stream that
  // automatically adds a new line and
  // flushes the stream on destruction
  CustomCoutStream stream(std::cout);

  // Note: This does not work because CustomCoutStream
  // cannot be converted to std::ostream
  return stream;
}
```

I want to create a trait like system that allows passing any kind of object that has a certain function (e.g `<<` overload operator). Is this something that can be achieveable. I am currently thinking of going the dynamic dispatch route and creating virtual functions. However, I want to know if there is a way to handle this with operator overloading (e.g overloading equality operator, the output stream operator etc).

Comment: Why would `logger.log` return a `std::ostream`? Couldn't you implement it as `void Logger::log(std::ostream& os, Severity severity, auto... messages)`?

Comment: In C++ "traits" are realized via concepts, which were introduced in C++20. You can write functions accepting any type that are constraint by some concept. Such a concept could for example be the requirement that certain member functions exist. Is this what you are looking for? Without C++20, you can mimic concepts with templates and SFINAE.

Comment: @rturrado The logger is the one who supplies the stream, not the user. The user just outputs to the stream.

Comment: @joergbrech I have heard of concepts but my understanding was that concepts are compile time operations. Can they work with dynamic objects . In my example above, I am setting a function dynamically (using setTransport). If I set the return value to be a class that adheres to this concept, I can quiet down the compiler but will they be resolved properly in runtime?

Comment: I probably haven't understood your problem entirely. Which function should only accept objects of a given trait? What will be the expected return type? The argument and return types of any function in C++ must be known at compile time, so checking type traits can also be done at compile time.

Comment: I have solved this issue in a different way that did not require concepts or SFINAE. However, I will still look into concepts as I want to upgrade my project to C++20 and see what it offers.